# Random variables and geometric series

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-series

**Q:** Consider the following random variable $Y$. It takes only values of the form $\frac 1{2^k}$ for positive integers $k$ and $P\left(Y= \frac 1{2^k}\right) = \frac 1{2^k}$ for each $k$. Find the expected value of this random variable.

I did find out that $a = \frac12$ in the geometric series but I am unable to find the proper result

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. You can take the help of [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to format your questions.

Comment: Better to add your attempt what you have tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General expression for expected value of a discrete random variable $X$.  Let $a_n$ be a value and let $p_n=P(X=a_n)$.  Then $E(X)=\sum a_np_n$  In your case $E(Y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k}}=\frac{1}{3}$.